# Pivot Table source update

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have looked at previously answered questions on this subject and tried to apply the answers to my macro but I keep getting run time errors (13)when I try to apply it.I would appreciate any help.

Code:

Sub TestPivot()

```
Dim test1 As Range

Set test1 = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("B1:T100000")

       Sheets("Summary").PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        test1 _
        , Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

Set test1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks,

Ciaran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it works:

```
Sub TestPivot()
       Dim test1 As String

       test1 = "'Raw Data!R1C2:R10000C20'"

       Sheets("Summary").PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        test1 _
        , Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

        test1 = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: I added the missing " and I got it to work.  I really apreciate your help.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that, I didn't realized that